# Service that works right for few hours, than no more response

Tags: android, service, ondestroy

I want to run a method CippaLippa() in the GmailService class when I receive an email in Gmail client.

I've a receiver and a service in AndroidManifest...

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.myapp.receiver.GmailReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.myapp.service.GmailService"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and these classes...

```
public class GmailReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {


        final SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("myapp.prefs", 0);

        context.startService(new Intent(context, GmailService.class));
    }
}


public class GmailService extends Service { .. etc...}
```

**My question:** everything works right for some hours and when I receive a notification from Gmail, the CippaLippa() method fires... then, after some hours, when I receive a gmail notification, the CippaLippa() method fires no more.

Maybe, there is a way to tell GmailService class to "stay alive" and continue monitoring Gmail events? I think this is not due to Android OS that kills unused classes, because that is a background service and not an Activity.
I've no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the system killing the service. I've had the same problem with a service associated with a widget.
I solved it by making it refresh every 30 minutes or so.

So if you schedule some event once in a while to wake up your service, it should stay up and running.

There might be a better solution though.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will start the alarm manager immediately (fire the PendingIntent) and run the task every 60 seconds.

```
    Intent logReader = new Intent();
    logReader.setClassName("com.foo.Test", "com.foo.Test.MyServiceClass");
    logReaderPI = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, logReader, 0);
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    AlarmManager aMgr =  (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    aMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, 60 * 1000, logReaderPI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [START_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY). I'm not sure if this will entirely do the trick, but it may help keep your service going.

Comment: I read on the web that this do the trick, theoretically... But, in practice I read that someone, using this way, after that Android killed his service killed to free memory, the service reloaded... BUT AFTER 6 HOURS!!